# Problems with unsing TKinter and RPi.GPIO together for Skeeball program

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm trying to make a program with Python that will be used for a skeeball game off of a raspberry pi.  I already have a script made up for having a simple 9 ball game using Tkinter and python.  My problem now is that I want to add more games such as a timed game or cricket for example and don't want to have to use the mouse to control the menus.  My original thought was to have tkinter frames stack on top of each other and pull the game that I wanted to the top.  I ran into way too many errors with GPIO not working properly with it (could have just been my inexperience but I decided to scrap that).  I now am trying to use code to pull up separate python scripts when a GPIO button is pressed using

`import subprocess
subprocess.call('/home/pi/Skeeball_python/Skeeball02.py'`

That code returned an error 13 with permission denied.  I gave root access to all the files and folders with my code in it and even was logged in as root user when I ran the program and still got the same error.

My question is how would I get this code to work in order to load separate scripts without returning an error and to also run as superuser since the GPIO part of the script needs root access.Should I keep trying with getting the separate script to load or should I try a different method?

If it's at all useful here is my 9 ball game code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from tkinter import *

Screen = Tk()
Screen.geometry ('1920x1080')
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup (17, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup (26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) #GPIO 26 as reset 

score = IntVar()
ballcount = IntVar()

score.set(0)
ballcount.set(9)

mLabel1 = Label(Screen,text = 'SCORE',fg = 'red',font=("helvatica", 100))
mLabel1.place(x='250',y='250')
mLabel2 = Label(Screen,text = 'BALLS REMAINING',fg = 'red',font=("helvatica", 40))
mLabel2.place(x='250',y='550')
mLabel3 = Label(Screen,textvariable = score,fg = 'red',font=("helvatica", 100))
mLabel3.place(x='950',y='250')
mLabel4 = Label(Screen,textvariable = ballcount,fg = 'red',font=("helvatica", 100))
mLabel4.place(x='950',y='500')
mLabel5 = Label(Screen,text = 'Press Button to Reset',fg = 'red',font=("helvatica", 40))
mLabel5.place(x='250',y='550')

mLabel5.place_forget()


def score100(self):
    if not ballcount.get()==0:
        score.set(score.get()+100)
        ballcount.set(ballcount.get()-1)            
    end()

def reset(self):
    score.set(0)
    ballcount.set(9)
    mLabel2.place(x='250',y='550')
    mLabel4.place(x='950',y='500')
    mLabel5.place_forget()
    LEDwindup()

def end():
    if ballcount.get() == 0:
        mLabel2.place_forget()
        mLabel4.place_forget()
        mLabel5.place(x='250',y='550')

GPIO.add_event_detect(17,GPIO.RISING,callback=score100,bouncetime=500)
GPIO.add_event_detect(26,GPIO.FALLING,callback=reset,bouncetime=500)


Screen.mainloop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

It's pretty rough yet and I'm still pretty inexperienced in python so any suggestions would help as well too on other things.

Comment: This is way too much code to post. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry I took out as much redundant code as possible

Comment: you can import scripts in main script and run them but in scripts you have to put code in functions or use classes and OOP - ie. `import script1 ;  script1.App().mainloop()`.

Comment: @furas would you be able to explain a little more?  I kindof know what you mean but not at the same time.  Are you saying to import script in a function? Or import at the beginning and just call on the class when I want to load the game?  Is there a way to unimport a script?

Comment: in main script you can import other script - if in other script you have all code in classes/functions then you can control when classes/functions will be executed. if memory is a problem then you can use `del` to remove imported script. ie `import math ;  print(math.pi) # 3.1415 ; del math ;  print(math.pi) # ERROR`